# How to start start an android emulator in eclipse while a device is connected?

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I click "run as an android application" in eclipse, the app only starts on my phone without asking if I want to start it on an emulator as well. I wish to have the app start on both my phone and an android emulator. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to menu Window -> AVD Manager and run the emulator from there.

You can also change the run configuration so that it will prompt you for a device (in that dialog you can start the emulator) instead of just using any attached device.

Answer (score 1):

On the Run menu select "Run configurations" then under Android Application find your project. Under the Target tab check the "Always prompt to pick device" option. After clicking Run, and in the future you should get a prompt asking you witch device you would like.